# AngularJS binding. How many watches it sets for a chain of properties of the same object?

Tags: angularjs

Please, I have a doubt about how many watches will set angular when I wrote this chain of bindings in my view:

```
<div>{{myobject.prop1}} - {{myobject.prop2}} - {{myobject.prop3}}</div>
```

Is it only one or three? If there are 3 watches then I'm going to rewrite these bindings like, thinking that I'll get a better performance:

```
<div>{{myobject.prop1 + " - " + myobject.prop2 + " - " + myobject.prop3}}</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will create three watches. However, if each property is just a basic data type like `string` or `number` you can leave it as it is because  Angular's digest cycle is already well optimised.

I don't think concatenating will bring any performance benefits because in this case Angular has to evaluate the entire expression during every digest loop to see whether any of them has changed so I believe this is going to be slower than the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You will have 3 watches in both cases. And actually it's not so big deal with performance when you have 3 watches.